# Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ is a Lipschitz function. Prove that if $g_n→g$ uniformly, then $f\circ g_n→f\circ g$ uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, function-and-relation-composition

Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ is a Lipschitz function (which means that there exists a number $K\ge 0$ such that $|f(x)−f(y)| \le K|x−y|$, for all $x, y\in \mathbb{R}$). Also, suppose that functions $g_n, g:\mathbb{R}^d→\mathbb{R}$ are all bounded. Prove that if $g_n→g$ uniformly, then $f\circ g_n→f\circ g$ uniformly.

So if $g_n \rightarrow g$, then for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists an $N>0$ such that $n \ge N$ implies $|g_n-g|<\epsilon$. Not sure if this will be needed for the proof. If $g_n \rightarrow g$ , I don't see why you cant just say $f(g(x))_n\rightarrow f(g(x))$, since it is given. What does applying $f$ have to do with changing the fact that $g_n\rightarrow g$?

Comment: $g$ and $g_n$ are functions rather than numbers, so what exactly do you mean by $|g_n - g| < \epsilon$? Do you understand the difference between pointwise and uniform convergence?

Comment: Regarding "what does applying $f$ have to do with changing the fact that $g_n \to g$?":

It might be helpful to see a counterexample for the case that $f$ is not Lipschitz. For example, consider the functions $f,g,g_n : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by
$$
g_n(x) = x + 1/n, \quad g(x) = x, \quad f(x) = x^2.
$$
Note that $(f\circ g_n - f \circ g)(x) = 2x/n + 1/n^2$, and we see that this function does not approach zero uniformly. It is certainly true, however, that because $f$ is continuous, $f \circ g_n$ will approach $f \circ g$ **pointwise**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** For all $x$,
$$|f \circ g_n(x) - f \circ g(x)| \leq K |g_n(x) - g(x)|$$

so $$||f \circ g_n - f \circ g ||_{\infty} \leq K ||g_n - g||_{\infty}$$

Comment: From here, would I say "let epsilon be $K||g_n-g||_{\infty}$, and thus $||f\circ g_n-f\circ g||<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon >0$? This is a definition of convergence I believe

Comment: No. If you choose $\varepsilon = K||g_n-g||_{\infty}$, then $\varepsilon$ depends on $n$, which does not make a lot of sense, and furthermore it would not be for *any* $\varepsilon$. But when you have the given inequality, just let $n$ tend to $+\infty$.